# How to search between encoded data in mysql database in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, encryption

I have encoded some data using codeigniter's encryption method and stored them in mysql database. There is no problem retrieving them, but when I want to search between them, it appears to be nonsense. How can I search between encoded data in mysql and codeigniter?

This is my encoding function:

```
function _encode($options = array()){

    $key = 'Q7tBBb1iECkl5Kk1U3mVPur1J863KGz4';

    $encoded = $this->encrypt->encode($options['code'], $key);

    return $encoded;
}
```

This is what I use as a search method in my Model:

```
function search()
{
    //Pagination config
    $search_by = $this->session->userdata('search_by');
    $search_term = $this->_encode($this->session->userdata('search_term'));

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'acp/cds/search_result/page/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->like($search_by, $search_term)->get('cards')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    $config['num_links'] = 4;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page_num = $this->uri->segment(5, 1);
    $offset = ($page_num - 1) * $config['per_page'];
    $this->db->order_by('card_Id', 'ASC');        
    $this->db->like($search_by, $search_term);
    $query = $this->db->get('cards', $config['per_page'], $offset);

    return $query->result();        
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you trying to search for data that is encrypted in the MySQL database?

Comment: yes ! I said the same thing in my question !

Comment: So in your table, the data is encrypted, correct? If you're doing that, you need to encrypt your search parameter first, then perform a SQL statement with that encrypted search param.

Comment: Encrypted search parameter doesn't seem to be the same as the one in the database while it has been encoded with the same encryption key.

Comment: That is because the cypher method does not create "static" content, it instead generates randomly based on a whole series of variables. This makes it impossible to search by "encryption". You could try finding a cypher that may be acceptable for you. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Comment: Thanks, but I asked how to do that?!

Comment: Please post your code and the schema of the table you want to search in.

Comment: I added my code to the question. you can check it out

Comment: So, what should I do? any suggestions?

Comment: Please post several rows from the db where you expected it to match but didn't, and the input you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->encrypt->sha1()` instead since you what to search by a "static" encryption string. All other cypher methods will give you random strings on every request, making it impossible to search by that string.

Comment: SHA1, just like MD5 is non-decodable.

Answer (score 0):

Your encryption function takes an array as the parameter with the stuff to be encrypted in the code key of the array.  However, when you call the encryption function in `search()` you are passing a normal parameter.  The third line of your `search()` function currently looks like this:

```
$search_term = $this->_encode($this->session->userdata('search_term'));
```

Change it to:

```
$search_term = $this->_encode(array('code' => $this->session->userdata('search_term')));
```

That said, I'm not really sure what you're hoping to gain by encrypting the data in this way, especially if the key you posted in that sample is the real key you are using.